# Convert Datetime format in SQL Server or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, c#-5.0

Can you please help me to convert the datetime to `2017-04-06T15:03:07+01:00` from `2017-04-06 15:03:07.000` (from SQL Server)?

Any code either C# or T-SQL

Comment: and what's stopping you doing that?

Comment: You can use ToString() on datetime instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `datetime` is your date time variable:

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:sszzz");
```

You will get a warning saying that this is not the recommended way to persist timezone information, however.

Comment: Can we convert the same in sql? tnx

Comment: I am not familiar with the exact syntax, but I believe you can use this method: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp